# Bash's 'hash' command always succeeds when trying to check existance of a command with a slash in the name

Tags: bash

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
hash ./a.sh  && echo ./a.sh exists
hash foo     && echo foo exists
hash bar/foo && echo bar/foo exists
bar/foo
```

It tries to check whether different commands exist, namely `./a.sh`, `foo` and `bar/foo` (e.g. a `foo` executable inside `bar` directory). Afterwards, it tries to run `bar/foo` command. My output is:

```
./a.sh exists
./a.sh: line 3: hash: foo: not found
bar/foo exists
./a.sh: line 5: bar/foo: No such file or directory
```

First two lines are expected, as well as the last one. However, the third line says that `hash` command did not fail for `bar/foo`, which is strange.

I have though that using "hash" is preferrable for testing existence of commands which the script is about to use. At least, it's mentioned as a possible alternative in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/767632). Turns out it does not work very well for commands which are relative paths (haven't tested with absolute paths). Why is that? `type` works better, but I considered them to be mostly synonymous.

Comment: `hash` and `type` are not synonymous. If you want to check the existence of a command you're better of relying on `which`, which was designed for that use case.

Comment: @ffledgling I've consulted with [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/767632), which recommends to avoid `which` and use builtin commands, because they provide same functionality, but do not require to spawn additional process.

Comment: Also, `hash` takes NAMES as arguments, not PATHS. It doesn't make sense to cache relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to bash's [documentation on how commands are looked up and executed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution):

> #### 3.7.2 Command Search and Execution
>
> After a command has been split into words, if it results in a simple
>   command and an optional list of arguments, the following actions are
>   taken.
>
> 1. ***If the command name contains no slashes, the shell attempts to locate it***. If there exists a shell function by that name, that
>      function is invoked as described in Shell Functions.
> 2. If the name does not match a function, the shell searches for it in the list of shell builtins. If a match is found, that builtin is
>      invoked.
> 3. ***If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, Bash searches each element of*** **`$PATH`**
>      ***for a directory containing an executable file by that name. Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files
>      to avoid multiple*** **`PATH`** ***searches (see the description of***
>      **`hash`** ***in Bourne Shell Builtins). A full search of the directories in*** **`$PATH`** ***is performed only if the command is
>      not found in the hash table***. If the search is unsuccessful, the
>      shell searches for a defined shell function named
>      `command_not_found_handle`. If that function exists, it is invoked
>      with the original command and the original command’s arguments as its
>      arguments, and the function’s exit status becomes the exit status of
>      the shell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error
>      message and returns an exit status of 127.
> 4. If the search is successful, ***or if the command name contains one or more slashes***, the shell executes the named program in a separate
>      execution environment. ...

In short, look-up and hashing is performed only for commands that do not contain slashes. If a command looks like a path (i.e. contains a slash) it is assumed to refer to en executable file at that path and the complex procedure of look-up is not needed. As a result, `hash` handles arguments with slashes as if they would resolve to themselves and exits with a success status unconditionally (that is without checking that the named file actually exists and is executable).